# How to make class having multiple state as thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, thread-safety

I have below class where

```
public class LRUCache {
   private HashMap<String,String> dataMap;
   private HashMap<String,String> analyticsMap;

   public put(String key, String value) {
       dataMap.put(key, value);
       String date = getCurrentDateAsString();
       analyticsMap.put(key, date);
   }
   public get(String key) {
       String date = analyticsMap.get(key);
       boolean dateExpired = isDateExpired(date);
       boolean value = null;
       if (!dateExpired)
           value = dataMap.get();
       return value;
   }
```

}

In the above class I have 2 hashmaps, which are being accessed in get and put methods. How do I make this class thread safe ?

Do I need to synchronize both get and put which should solve my problem?
In general if I have more than 1 state in class, then instead of making each of using 2 concurrentHashMaps, should I be putting them in a synchronized method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely using `ConcurrentHashMap` structures doesn't make your `LRUCache` class thread-safe.  You'd need to properly control access so no other thread can modify the underlying contents when you're doing multi-step put/get operations. This can be accomplished with `synchronized` methods, or with `ReentrantReadWriteLock` read/write locks.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

From the official Javadoc (my highlights) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html :

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and high
>   expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
>   specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of Hashtable. **However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail
>   locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in
>   a way that prevents all access.** This class is fully interoperable with
>   Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its
>   synchronization details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `ReentrantLock`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html then you can just synchronize a block rather than the whole method.